# How to clear the previous interval and run a new one

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new in Node JS, my job is really simple: just clear the exiting interval and run a new on every user button click.

I've tried using `global.clearInterval`, but it didn't work

```js
function time() {
    if (today.getTime() === subuh.getTime()){
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, notifikasi)
    }
    console.log(today.toTimeString)
}
clearInterval(clock);
var clock = setInterval(time, 1000);
```

What I expect is `var clock` is cleared before `setInterval`

Please help me, help me solve this and make me sleep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need two functions here: one will be called when the user clicks the button (I called it `restart()`) - it will clear the previous timer and start a new one. And the second function is what you actually want to be repeated every second and what you pass to the `setInterval` (I just log the current timer id).

Check out this example:

```js
var timer;

function time() {
  console.log('Timer ID:', timer);
}

function restart() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(time, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="restart()">(Re)start</button>
```

Comment: your answer looks perfect, but 1 question, i code functions in firebase cloud functions, that functions i wrote its only for 1 user or for every user ? because i wrote var Timer, and i scare every user who download my app will access var Timer together

Comment: @faufau it depends on how you call these functions from the front end. If you want a  different timer for each user, you may need to store the timer ids in a collection, but in this case you will have to pass some user identifier to get the corresponding timer, right? For example, you could have a map where keys are user ids and values are timer ids, so every user would get their own timer.

Answer (score 0):

Before your call to `clearInterval(clock);` the variable clock does not exist as such you should get a reference error of clock not being defined. You can however be able to clear value of clock after the call to set interval. this is because the variable clock only start existing after the call to set `var clock = setInterval(time, 1000);` Alternatively, you could define clock before you call clearInterval.

```
function time() {
        if (today.getTime() === subuh.getTime()){
            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, notifikasi)
        }
        console.log(today.toTimeString)
      }
    var clock;
    clearInterval(clock);
    clock = setInterval(time, 1000);
```

Either way, it is the same as doing this 
`var clock = setInterval(time, 1000);` and clearing the interval at some point when some certain event occur.

Comment: I must point out, moving `var clock;` as you have is pointless. That's effectively happening in OP's code - the declaration (not to be confused with its assignment) is hoisted to the top of the scope regardless. When `clearInterval()` runs the first time, `clock` is `undefined` in both your code and OP's. There is no ReferenceError.

Comment: @deefour any solutions ?